# i have a problem with SQL command, everyone help me please?

Tags: java

```
String sql = "update staff set Name = \""+txtName.getText()+"\",Age = "+Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText())+",Gender ="+cbGender.getSelectedItem().toString()+",Email = "+txtEmail.getText()+", Phone = "+txtPhone.getText()+", Salary ="+txtSalary.getText()+"where ID=\""+staff.elementAt(0)+"\"";
```

and error said that:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ID="2"' at line 1

I see it very carefully but i dont know what wrong in this syntax

Comment: Even if you fix your error, it is a bad idea to build a SQL statement using string concatenation, in this way. Take a look at [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead: _the most important advantage of prepared statements is that they help prevent SQL injection attacks_.

Comment: Most likely reason is that it can't find a comma or a where clause before the ID field. You need a space before the word where in the `"where ID=\""`. However, listen to @andrewjames - it's good advice - don't build your sql statement using string concatenation.